# Проблема в правильном использовании асинхронного useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, асинхронность

Пытаюсь написать асинхронный юз эффект, что бы в зависимости от значения стейта рендерился определенный вариант страницы.

```js
export const RecoveryPasswordForm = () => {
  const [requestKey, setrequestKey] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      try {
        await axios.get(API_URL + RECOVERY_KEY);
        setrequestKey(true);
      } catch (e) {
        setrequestKey(false);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(requestKey);
      }
    })();
  }, [requestKey]);

if (requestKey === true) {
    return (....)
}
 if (requestKey === false) {
    return (.....)
}
```

По факту у меня выстреливает ошибка из-за того, что блоки не могу отрендериться, так как на момент рендера стейт все так же равен null.
Вопрос в том, что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD START**

Не сразу увидел, но у вас `useEffect()` будет зациклен, поскольку он зависит от изменения переменной `requestKey` и сам же ее меняет.

если нужно спрашивать один раз при загрузке, тогда оставьте пустой массив в конце

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    .....
        console.log(requestKey);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

Иначе передумывайте логику.

**UPD END**

Первое: можно определить одно из состояний при инициализации

```js
const [requestKey, setrequestKey] = useState(false); // либо true
```

Второе: можно добавить условие для `requestKey === null`

```js
if (requestKey !== null){
    if (requestKey === true) {
      return (....)
  }
   if (requestKey === false) {
      return (.....)
  }
} else {
  return (// какой нибудь лоадер, который сменится когда прилетит requestKey (true/false))
}
```

Comment: зацикливание будет только в случае, если каждый раз будет меняться значение requestKey, в данном случае скорее все зацикливания не будет.

Comment: @Grundy "скорей всего", мы же не знаем, что прилетает по запросу. Много раз сталкивался с таким багом, поэтому и обратил внимание. И как минимум запрос будет дважды отправлен, когда этого можно избежать

Comment: Второй вариант сработал. Спасибо за помощь.